# RevMobAds - Test video ads not loading?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ads, revmob

Ive opted towards RevMob since the iAd network isn't accepting new apps and I'm trying to put a video ad after a round of my game is played like this:

```
func gameOver() {
      RevMobAds.session().fullscreen().loadVideo()
          RevMobAds.session().fullscreen().showVideo()
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
    let gameScene = GameOver(size: self.size)

    self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
     }
```

My fullscreen and banner ads are working perfectly, but when I end the game to load the video, I get this in the console with no ad being shown:

```
 [RevMob] Ad received: (200) - 56ba71998e700003764c65b9
```

Is anyone else having this problem? If so, have you fixed it?

Comment: How do you mean iAd isn't accepting new apps?

Comment: They're not approving new apps for their network although existing apps will continue with them until June 30th. Check iTunes connect for a more detailed description.

Comment: Good to know i was just planning to use it.

Comment: I don't have a  iTunes connect account and i can't i further see anywhere that it is out of business.

Answer (score 0):

We have changed our documentation, please checkout the updated one [here](https://revmobmobileadnetwork.com/sdk/ios_full#content-video).

What I believe is happening is that you are not saving the fullscreen object. You should create a fullscreen object and save it into a variable:
`video = RevMobAds.session().fullscreen()`

Then you can load a video ad into the fullscreen object: `video!.loadVideo()`

And then showVideo on the fullscreen object: `video!.showVideo()`

Note that loadVideo() is an asynchronous call, so you should either call the methods with completion handlers or extend our delegate classes.

Best regards,

Comment: Hey my test banner ads won't load... Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894706/revmob-banner-ads-wont-display