# RevMob banner ads won't display

Tags: swift, revmob

Alright so this is the code I'm using but banner ads won't seem to load up. Testing mode is on but nothing shows up at all.

```
let completionBlock: () -> Void = {
    //Custom method defined below
    self.banner?.showAd()
    self.bannerView?.showAd()

}
let failureBlock: (NSError!) -> Void = {error in
    print("Gifting Chaos Session failed to start with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

RevMobAds.startSession(withAppID: "myKEY", withSuccessHandler: completionBlock, andFailHandler: nil)
bannerView? = RevMobAds.session().bannerView()
let x = CGFloat(0)
let y = CGFloat(0)
let width = CGFloat(375)
let height = CGFloat(50)
self.bannerView?.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
bannerView?.loadAd()
bannerView?.showAd()
banner?.releaseAd()
self.banner?.showAd()
```

Comment: I would advise using AdMob, but that is your decision I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is a bit confusing. You call `showAd()` and also `releaseAd()`. Could you try to just show the ad in the completion block? Also try using our Sample App and follow our documentation [here](https://revmobmobileadnetwork.com/sdk/ios_full)

You didn't send the code that is in your viewController, but you also have to add the banner in your controller's view.

Comment: Yes I made those changes but no result

Comment: Btw - you guys need to update your app. Crashes with BUNCH of syntax errors so I can't even run.

Comment: Also, there is no way that the ad will not move locations. I see a blank view on the bottom which won't even go to the top

Comment: I've been trying to move it to the top of the screen all day and there has been no luck. Your documentation is ZERO help because its outdated and it won't work.

Comment: We will update our sample app and documentation as soon as possible